# Php response showing inputs instead of only data

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I've got a simple form with 2 fields. I want when the form is submitted i show the value of the fields into a div, but i has to go fo a php file first.

Script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function() {
            $.post($(this).attr("form.php"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#capacontenidora").html(data);
            });
            return false; // prevent normal submit
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form method="post">
    <div>Camp:<input type="text" id="camp1" value="valor1" name="valor1"></div>
    <div style="text-align-top;">Camp2:<input id="camp2" value="valor2" name="valor2"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="enviar"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="capacontenidora">
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['valor1']." ".$_POST['valor2'];
?>
```

The problem is that it prints the inputs with the values again and I would like to just print the values... I think is something to do with serialize() but i really dont know how to fix it, any ideas? Thank you very much guys!

Comment: What output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: $(this).attr() should contain the name of the attr not the value of the attr this should be something like this $(this).attr("action", "form.php");

Comment: @GhulamAli i want to show the values of the 2 inputs and im getting the input with the value, do u understand what i mean?

Comment: And @RahulSingh that doesnt seem to work, coz now it doesnt show anything :S. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your input2: valor2 does not have type tag. Make it like <input id="camp2" value="valor2" name="valor2" type="text"> and try.

Comment: That did'nt work either. And it has to be $(this).attr("form.php"), without the action!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, found some code in other post and actually worked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $.post('form.php', $('form').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
                     $('#capacontenidora').html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```